# WHERE clause causes error "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on an HR base. Why am I not able to type a statement like this?

```
SELECT  id_dzialu, sum(placa) as suma 
FROM    pracownicy
WHERE   suma = 8000
GROUP BY id_dzialu
```

When I try it, it returns an error:

`"%s: invalid identifier"`

Answer (score 10):

In short, you can't reference aggregated functions in a `where` clause because at the time the `where` clause is processed the aggregation has not yet been performed. Use a `having` clause instead.

Comment: thank you 1 more question. Why if i type

<code>
select id_dzialu, sum(placa) as suma from pracownicy
group by id_dzialu 
having suma = 80000
</code>

I still get an error?

Comment: That will depend on the DBMS you use. In Oracle you'll get an error while in MySQL you won't. The must-work solution is `having sum(placa) = 80000`. Check that out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the HAVING clause.

For Oracle, the query should be

```
select id_dzialu, sum(placa) as suma from pracownicy group by id_dzialu having sum(placa) = 8000
```

Comment: you should remove where clause and it is 8000 instead of 80000